# Tried to get location before initializing timezone database

Tags: flutter, notifications

I am trying to schedule a notification:but I got this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Tried to get location before initializing timezone database

Although I initialized the Timezone in the init function:

```
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
```

schedule code:

```
  Future<void> scheduleNotifications(String title,int yy,int mm,int dd,int hh,int ii) async {
 
    final   loc_egypt = tz.getLocation('Africa/Cairo');       
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(loc_egypt);
    var schedule_30before=tz.TZDateTime(loc_egypt,yy,mm,dd,hh,ii).subtract(Duration(minutes: 30));


      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          0,
          title,
          "The Webinar will start after 30 minutes",
          schedule_30before,
          NotificationDetails(android: _androidNotificationDetails),
          androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);


  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `main()` method of your app, verify your imports and call the init method

```
//Pick one of the three following imports : 

//If you just want the latest
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

//If you use the 10y db variant
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_10y.dart' as tz; 

//If you want to import all the db variants
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;


void main() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was with invalid assets. I am working on a Flutter Web project, so I was doing:

```dart
import 'package:timezone/browser.dart' as tz;

void main() async {
  await tz.initializeTimeZone();
  // other stuff
}
```

After digging into the source code of `timezone` package, I discovered that it is initialising using a `*.tzf` file, which I wasn't including in my project's assets (rookie's mistake). So I edited my `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/timezone/data/latest.tzf
#    - packages/timezone/data/latest_all.tzf <- for all the db variants
#    - packages/timezone/data/latest_10y.tzf <- for 10y db variant
```

But there was still one more thing to do. As it turns out `tz.initializeTimeZone()` assumes that a default path is `packages/timezone/data/latest.tzf` BUT my Flutter Web project was putting all the assets in `assets` catalogue, so the actual path was `assets/packages/timezone/data/latest.tzf` and I just had to pass it as an argument to `tz.initializeTimeZone('assets/packages/timezone/data/$dbVariant')`. Of course you need to replace $dbVariant with the variant of your choice, the one that you included in your assets.

**TL;DR**

1. Include a timezone database in assets:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/timezone/data/latest.tzf
```

2. Initialise timezone with a full path to assets:

```dart
import 'package:timezone/browser.dart' as tz;

void main() async {
  await tz.initializeTimeZone('assets/packages/timezone/data/latest.tzf');
  // other stuff
}
```

Comment: For reference, there is an issue ongoing on Flutter's Github explaining why you had to do that : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67655

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the following packages:

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tzl;
import 'package:timezone/standalone.dart' as tz;
```

Then, you can call for example something like:

```
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: ()async {
             await scheduleNotifications("title", 2022, 9, 1, 1, 47); 
          },
          child: Text("Notify Me!"))
```

Given you put `tzl.initializeTimeZones();` in your initState().

Your issue is in using `initializeTimeZones()` of a package different than `"package:timezone/data/latest.dart"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I created a future method and initialized it in the main() function of the main.dart file. This is my code:

```
import 'package:timezone/browser.dart' as tz;

Future<void> main() async {
  initTimeZone();
  // add other setup here
}

void initTimeZone(){
   tz.initializeTimeZones();
}
```

Hope this helps!